# adding string to a List<string> with razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to add an array of strings in TempData["scripts"], but first I need to see if the string already exist... If it exist don't add it... else add it to the array.

This is what I have so far... It add the strings to the array... but I need to check the Tempdata first so it doesn't take duplicates...

```
@{
        var scripts = (List<string>)TempData["scripts"];
        scripts.Add("../Scripts/test.js");
        scripts.Add("../Scripts/testv.js");
        scripts.Add("../Scripts/testh.js");
    }
```

Comment: can't you use `if` or just call `.Distinct()` afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

```
@{
        var scripts = (List<string>)TempData["scripts"];
        if(scripts.Contains("../Scripts/test.js") == false)
        {
             scripts.Add("../Scripts/test.js");
        }
        //repeat with the others
    }
```

Comment: this is great but I would need a function to pass "../Scripts/test.js" as an argument... because I may have 10 files to add...

Comment: this way I can have a list of  filespath in an array and create a forloop to inject it... do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

### Edit to reflect your answer

Assuming `TempData["scripts"]` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, you can do this more simply:

```
var scripts = (HashSet<string>)TempData["scripts"];
string[] path = {
    "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.js",
    "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js",
    "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.selection.min.js",
    "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.animator.min.js",
    "../Scripts/jquery-sparkline/jquery-sparkline.js"
};

foreach (var item in path)
    scripts.Add(item);
```

There's no need to check for duplicates this way.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to be able to pass the path as an argument so I don't have to repeat it twice every time

```
 @{
        var scripts = (List<string>)TempData["scripts"];
        string[] path = {
            "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.js",
            "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js",
            "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.selection.min.js",
            "../Scripts/jquery-flot/jquery.flot.animator.min.js",
            "../Scripts/jquery-sparkline/jquery-sparkline.js"
        };
        foreach (var item in path)
        {
            if (scripts.Contains(item) == false) { scripts.Add(item); }
        }
    }
```